# How to refresh and display current output request in ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, filtering

I want to do filtering using ajax call to get data. The filtering works fine, however, I detect a bug. When the first time click the search button 'cari', it displays the result. For example Ali, John, Ray. For second time search, it displays the second result for example Tom, Alice, Roy. It listed in the array. But, the last data in first display list, Ray also attached in the second result displayed.So, the second list display Tom, Alice, Roy and Ray. Although the array in console only Tom, Alice, Roy.

This is the ajax call code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $( "#cari" ).click(function() {
        // alert($('#section').val());
        var seksyen = $("#section").val();
        var status_pro= $("#statuspro").val();
        var bangsa_id= $("#bangsa").val();
        var agama_id= $("#agama").val();
        var jantina_id= $("#jantina").val();
        var negeri_id= $("#negeri").val();
        var kahwin_id= $("#status_kahwin").val();
         $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('kakitangan') }}?'+ $.param({'section': seksyen,'statuspro': status_pro,'bangsa': bangsa_id,'agama': agama_id,'jantina': jantina_id,'negeri': negeri_id,'status_kahwin': kahwin_id}),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#datatable tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
                var html = '';
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                    }   
                $('#datatable tr').first().after(html);
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
      });
  </script>
```

The html code is here:

```
     <!-- Carian mengikut seksyen -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                {{ Form::label('Seksyen', 'Seksyen') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                {{ Form::select('section', $sections, '', ['id' => 'section','class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- Carian mengikut status -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::label('Status', 'Status Kakitangan') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::select('statuspro', $statuspro, '', ['id' => 'statuspro', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        <!-- Carian mengikut kategori dan pangkat -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <label for="kategori">Kategori:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3"> 
                  <select name="kategori" class="form-control select2" style="width:250px">
                      <option value="">-- pilih --</option>
                      @foreach ($categories as $key => $value)
                      <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <label for="pang">Pangkat:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6"> 
                  <select name="pangkat" class="form-control select2"style="width:500px">
                  <option>-- pilih --</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Carian mengikut bangsa -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::label('Bangsa', 'Bangsa') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::select('bangsa', $bangsa, '', ['id' => 'bangsa', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Carian mengikut agama -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::label('Agama', 'Agama') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::select('agama', $agama, '', ['id' => 'agama', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Carian mengikut jantina -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::label('Jantina', 'Jantina') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::select('jantina', $jantina, '', ['id' => 'jantina', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Carian mengikut negeri lahir -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::label('negeri_lahir_peg', 'Negeri Lahir Pegawai') 
   }} 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 

               {{ Form::select('negeri_lahir', $negeri, '', ['id' => 'negeri_lahir', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Carian mengikut status perkahwinan -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::label('Status_kahwin', 'Status Perkahwinan') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                  {{ Form::select('status_kahwin', $kahwin, '', ['id' => 'status_kahwin', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

The datatable code:

```
 <div class="container table-responsive col-lg-12">
                                    <!-- <div class="container text-center"> -->      
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="datatable" >

                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Nama</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    <!-- </div> -->

                                </div>
```

Why the last data still attached to the next search? Although the searching continues for 4th or 5th times, the last data still attached to it. In this example, Roy.

Comment: You haven't shown us your HTML, so we can only guess at what it looks like.  I can guess that your first `tr` is some kind of header row, which you want to keep around between refreshes, so that explains `.not(':first')`. But why would you want to keep the last `tr` as well (`.not(':last')`)?

Comment: Thank you Don't Panic, you are right. I should not put the .not(':last') element inside the code. I mistakenly put it for footer element before..but removed later. You can answer below and I will accept your answer.